# Execute PowerShell script without waiting for result

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I try to execute a PowerShell script from c# without waiting for the result.

```
 string cmdArg = "MyScript.ps1";
 //Create New Runspace
 Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
 runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
 runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
 runspace.Open();

 //Adds the command
 pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmdArg);
 pipeline.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);

 //Do not wait for a result
 pipeline.InvokeAsync();
 runspace.Close();
```

But it waits until the script has finished!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeginInvoke` - as highlighted in this msdn sample - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706580(v=vs.85).aspx. The script is run `asynchronously` and `events are used to handle the output`.

```
// Invoke the pipeline asynchronously.
IAsyncResult asyncResult = powershell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms569311(v=vs.85).aspx

The Remarks state that you should use RunSpace.OpenAsync() method for asynch....